# problems with apply function in pandas after update

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I can't run a certain piece of code with a new version `0.9.1` of Pandas (under Python 2.7) from previous version.
The code I run is the following:

```
myfunc = lambda x: makeDfCurve(frame,x)
dates = Series(frame.index, index = frame.index) # new Time series filled temporarily 
# with dates taken from a certain dataframe 'frame' index
# and here's where the code crash:
frame['curve'] = dates.apply(myfunc)
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' not supported for the input types, and the inputs
>          could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule 'safe'

I tried to recurse the function to see if some of the dates passed as the x parameter in the lambda definition where wrong, but I got the correct results for any time. However the method does not work anymore and I have no clue why. I would appreciate your help and thoughts on it.

Thanks

P.S. I'd like to edit my question with the following, since, in fact, after further investigation:

This error is due the with of the new version of Pandas : the index of a TimeSeries is of a "class 'pandas.lib.Timestamp'" type, thus it creates a problem for my function where that it expects a datetime object instead.

Comment: it's just a basic function that needs a datetime.datetime value, I'll edit my question to provide further info on this.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my issue by checking the new version's documentation, where it is explained how index are now treated as timestamp [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew.html) thus using .to_pydatetime() method to convert the index values in proper datetime objects, as required by my function.